# How to customize the height of a bootstrap row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap. There for I am using the grid system as shown in the following code snippet:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
    <div class="col-lg">
        First
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="col-lg">
        Second
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want the first row to fill 90% of the screen and the second row 10%. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify viewport as height. viewport is the part of the website that is visible to the browser window

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: aliceblue; height: 90vh;"> </div>

<div class="row" style="background-color: red; height: 10vh;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set the height of the Body and the Container (parent of rows) to 100%.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid fill">
        <div class="row-fluid vh-40" style="background-color: blue;">
            <div class="col-lg">
                d90
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid vh-10" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="col-lg">
                d10
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

More informations :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/

In responsive, use vh (height relative to the viewport).

Good continuation.

_Teddy_